# C# Grep in Selenium

Tags: c#, regex, testing, selenium

I'm stuck! I was wondering if anyone had an idea to this problem. 
Basically there are 'keys' on a huge webpage in this format `*.*.*` (no other text will have that format)

My test suite is to check if all the keys in above format are in my dictionary list (which already exist - but there could be a situation where a key might not be in the diction). 
If there are keys that are not in the list then it should output a list of keys that are not in it and what page it was found in.
Is there a similar way to 'grep' all the text contains this regular expression of `*.*.*` ?

Again this is a huge site so it'll be hard to traverse through all the pages. However if there is no other way is there way to grab only the string of this format `*.*.*`

Thanks guys any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some examples of what strings follow the format `*.*.*`? Considering those are both characters used for wildcards in different circumstances, it's not too clear.

Comment: for example the site will have variable names in text (that is visual displayed)

`<a id="DocumentType1_link" data-facetselected="false" data-facetkey="DATA">ELEMENT.ReferencesType.Alternative:Alternative</a>`

As per above example it the key is ELEMENT.ReferenceType.Alternative value is Alternative

Comment: so i need to basically grep all the keys in `*.*.*` format on that page and check if it contains in my dictionary if not i'll output in a list. Is there a better way to do this rather than By.XPath[regEXP]

Comment: You can use `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-facetkey='DATA']"))` if all of your them have that attribute and attribute value.

Comment: As a rough draft at least, here's a regex that oughta work: `\b(.+\..+\..+):(.+)\b` (group 1 is the key, group 2 is the value)

Comment: Pete no here is an example of the key in a table
`<td class="co_Table_cell">TABLE.ReferencesContentType.Decisions:Cellar </td>`

So they basically popup anywhere on the page with the `*.*.*` format

Comment: Tim Thanks for the regex!!
Now i wonder if there was a way to (almost like HTML parse) through the entire site and check for that REGex

Answer (score 0):

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w*\.\w*\.\w*");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(searchText);
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
          //your code here
        }
```

Hope this helps!