# c# - HTML Parsing

Tags: c#, html, selenium, html-parsing

I got a webpage that i need to parse through the entire HTML code to find any special tagging.

For example i want to pull out all the `*.*.*` element on that page. Whats the best way to do this in c#?

However these strings are dynamic because they are resulting from a search query. So i can't just pull out the source code and look for that string since they are in scripts that gets pulled in dynamically.

Is there a way to get these strings? I just need to check if they are in my already existing list. Maybe Selenium? or some other engine that i'm not aware off or a good approach to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if they are related, so i'm not going to vote duplicate, but have you looked at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644468/c-sharp-grep-in-selenium

Comment: @sircapsalot the other entry is from same author. So I assume: yes, it seems like both times the question how to grep the html output of scripts and search for tags. lynx:  webBrowser.Navigate("thaPage"); use an event for DocumentCompleted and then just-> HtmlElementCollection htmlElements = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("someTag"); to get all elements named someTag

Comment: If you just want to scrape the page, and it isn't terribly complex (i.e, not much Javascript going on), then HtmlAgilityPack will do this just fine. Selenium can also do it, but HtmlAgilityPack is much more geared towards pure HTML scraping.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply guys. Yeah it's my old post :( I didn't quiet get the answer i was looking for so i thought i could make it clear. 
Offler: i don't want to get the tagname instead i want the text that is being displayed when a module is turned on
@Arran The only reason i'm using it in Selenium is because it's a huge login script and everything to get to the page i'm at and to recreate that in Agiligy pack would be too much to do. Because we are doing all our test in Selenium.


Is there a way to do it using XPath? text()? Thanks guys